# Code blocks aren't working correctly when placed after a list

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing

There seems to be something wrong with the code formatting blocks.
It seems to be correctly working when done, like so:

```
Working!
     Definitely working.
```

But, when placed after a list (markdown first then result):

```
1. This is a list.
2. This is a second item in the list.

    This is some code formatted text.
```

Now, this is what it looks like:

1. This is a list.
2. This is a second item in the list.

   This is some code formatted text.

As you can see, it is not formatting correctly, and unlike quotes -  There is no background... And the mono-spaced font (Courier New) is appearing like normal text (Arial).
Also, the space between the box and the start of the line is indeed an indent. (Not a bunch of spaces)

> A quote has a background; shading, like so.

---

In case, this is what it looks like with the bug; formatting not done correctly (in case it's fixed and the above looks correct):

[image: Markup isn't working after a list.]

---

Edit: See [this comment](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10484/code-blocks-arent-working-correctly-when-placed-after-a-list?noredirect=1#comment31121_10484)

> Huh. Adding any text between the numbered list and the code-formatted text fixes it, so this definitely seems fishy. –  StrixVaria♦

I tried completing the list. Also broke.

```
1. This is a list.
2. This is the second item.

    This should be preformatted text.

3. Now I've completed the list; closed it off around the coded text.
```

1. This is a list.
2. This is the second item.

   This should be preformatted text.
3. Now I've completed the list; closed it off and around the coded text.

Still broken. (Backup image in case):

[image: Broken still]

Comment: Huh. Adding any text between the numbered list and the code-formatted text fixes it, so this definitely seems fishy.

Comment: @StrixVaria Odd. It's not working for me.

Comment: Oh, I believe this is implemented this way so that you can have multi-paragraph entries within a single numeric bullet. If you add another number after, it keeps counting up at 3.

Comment: When in doubt, `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [migration to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348754/179041) as of June 2020, you can now use three backticks to denote a code block. This more explicit format leaves no room for the renderer to have to guess whether your spacing is part of the list or part of a code block. For example:

#### Pre-formatted:

````
- List Item 1
```
This sits between 2 list items, but is not indented so it is not part of the list
```
- List Item 2
  ```
  This is indented, as it is part of List Item 2
  ```
```
  This is not a part of the list despite bumping right up against the previous code block
```
````

#### Result:

- List Item 1

```
This sits between 2 list items, but is not indented so it is not part of the list
```

- List Item 2

  ```
  This is indented, as it is part of List Item 2
  ```

```
  This is not a part of the list despite bumping right up against the previous code block
```

Answer (score 2):

## Solution One

```
1. This is a list.
2. This is a second item in the list.

If you put some text here...

    ...then this text renders fine.
```

---

1. This is a list.
2. This is a second item in the list.

If you put some text here...

```
...then this text renders fine.
```

---

You need actual paragraph text in between your list and your code text. This is because, without that, the spaces at the beginning of the line (since you're mid-list) are assumed to mean that you want a new paragraph *within* the current bullet, rather than code-formatted text.

## Solution Two

```
1. This is a list.
2. This is a second item in the list.

        Here's some code-formatted text within a list.
```

---

1. This is a list.
2. This is a second item in the list.

   ```
   Here's some code-formatted text within a list.
   ```

---

To get this result, you just need to add a bunch more spaces until it works. This code-formatted text now counts as being within the bulleted list. If you really want top-level code-formatted text, you will need an interceding paragraph.

Comment: *Waits 1 minute to accept.* "You have to wait another minute."

Answer (score 2):

```
* List Item
* List Item

&nbsp;

    code block
```

---

- List Item
- List Item

```
code block
```

Comment: There's a bit of extra space, though.

Comment: #90sWebHacksForLife

Answer (score 1):

In the case of crash dumps, I've found that [adding a simple line break](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/214680/28182)  (`---`) is an elegant way to solve this issue, meaning this:

```
**System Info:**

- **Minecraft Version:** 1.6.4
- **Operating System:** Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.7.5
- **Java Version:** 1.6.0_65, Apple Inc.

---
    ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
    // Oops.

    Time: 4/19/15 5:58 PM
```

Becomes this:

**System Info:**

- **Minecraft Version:** 1.6.4
- **Operating System:** Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.7.5
- **Java Version:** 1.6.0_65, Apple Inc.

---

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Oops.

Time: 4/19/15 5:58 PM
```